# Does QGIS have Generalization toolset like ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: qgis, generalization

In ArcGIS Desktop there are Generalization tools like:

1. Merge Divided Roads
2. Collapse Road Detail
3. Resolve Road Conflicts

Does QGIS have this toolset or is it possible to run these algorithms on QGIS?

Comment: No -- not out of the box. There's a WIP plugin you can download and manually install from https://github.com/north-road/qgis-cartography-tools which offers some of these tools, but it's currently very "raw"

Comment: @ndawson Does there exist any documentation anywhere that lists what tools the plugin includes, or how to use them? I personally am seeking a tool like "Merge divided roads"